# how do I store a value from a date and time form

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a reminder app I am working on and I'm not able to store the date and time, only the name and a description. For now I just need to get it into local storage and then deal with retrieving the later.

```js
let reminders = [];
const addReminders = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let reminder = {
    ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
    InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
  }
  localStorage.setItem('ReminderInput', JSON.stringify(ReminderInput));
  localStorage.setItem('InfoInput', JSON.stringify(InfoInput));
  localStorage.setItem('DateInput'  JSON.stringify(DateInput));
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addReminders);
});
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">

  <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">

  <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
  <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..." id="InfoInput"></textarea>
  
  <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hers' the code that needs to be corrected, screenshot to show it works:

```
    let reminder = {
        ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
        InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value,
        DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value
    }
    localStorage.setItem('ReminderInput', JSON.stringify(reminder.ReminderInput));
    localStorage.setItem('InfoInput', JSON.stringify(reminder.InfoInput));
    localStorage.setItem('DateInput',JSON.stringify(reminder.DateInput));
}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. just what I need